# Load images after page load

Tags: javascript

I just heard somewhere that by using some javascript it is possible to load of a page after the entire page load completes,

When I googled, I found [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), but it seems that latest browsers are not supporting it.

My site has some images because of which sites becomes slow, is it possible to load images after the completion of page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at it on Github: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload - it appears that there was some sort of fix that was merged in that helps, though I'm not sure if it really fixes the issue. It appears to work for me as expected in FF6, though my connection is probably not slow enough to really notice much of a difference.

There's a WP plugin for Lazy Load that looks like it's working just fine for people and has been updated fairly recently: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-image-lazy-loading/. I'd say it doesn't hurt to try it out and see if that works. Who knows, perhaps the developer just hasn't updated the warning in a while!

Comment: After using the lazyload plugin for WP, it seems my site working on a jet speed, thank helenhousandi, +1 to you
:)